# how to do this disparity map in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

[paper "Fast Obstacle Detection Using U-Disparity Maps with Stereo Vision"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtQXs.jpg)

reference paper: "Fast Obstacle Detection Using U-Disparity Maps with Stereo Vision"

[image]

I want to ask can opencv do this reslut?
How?
Thank you

Thanks for @Liew Xun's comment.
Input are left image and right image from two camera.(stereo camera)
I want to use opencv's cv2.StereoBM to do the result like the paper's image.
But,unfortunately i failed. I can't make the result like this paper's image.
So i am here to ask does anybody have the same experience do disparity map.
Can you give me a help or give me some advice?

Comment: To help other people answer your question, please add more details to it like: What is your input? What is your expected output? What have you tried or researched? (a code snippet of what you have done would be good).

Comment: Thanks for Liew Xun's comment. I just adjusted my question.

Comment: ask OpenCV author for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is a mobile robotics visual perception related question.

I guess this author made a trick on you as it is not called U disparity

The stereo depth can be computed by opencv stereo matching. If you fail, there could be many reason. you need to post what you have.  you can follow this link to get depth map.  https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html

This right image is done by concatenating depth observation along the vertical plane.  It is called V disparity.  For normal road scene, most of the background road should be on the same straight line spam diagonally. Anything not on this line can be considered as an obstacle above or below the road surface.  When the sensing distance is far, there might be deformation for the line because of stereo uncertainty. This algorithm is designed to detect cases such as negative obstacle(drains, potholes)  and positive obstacle( cars humans）

you can find a sample implementation here

https://github.com/thinkbell/v_disparity

If you are Phd candidate, you need to read a lot more paper to know whether some paper is lying on their contribution rather than post question here and hope someone can tell you the answer.

[image]

Regards

Dr Yuan Shenghai