# Cut faraway objects based on depth map

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to do grabcut which uses a depth map that cuts away far objects, that is used in mixed reality application. So I would like to show just the front of what I see and the background as virtual reality scene.

The problem right now I tried to adapt so code and what I get is front which is cut but in black color, the mask actually.

I don't know where is the problem settle.

The input is a depth map from zed camera.
here is a picture of the behaviour:
[image]

My trial:

```
 private void convertToGrayScaleValues(Mat mask)
        {
            int width = mask.rows();
            int height = mask.cols();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[width * height];
            mask.get(0, 0, buffer);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    int value = buffer[y * width + x];

                    if (value == Imgproc.GC_BGD)
                    {
                        buffer[y * width + x] = 0; // for sure background
                    }
                    else if (value == Imgproc.GC_PR_BGD)
                    {
                        buffer[y * width + x] = 85; // probably background
                    }
                    else if (value == Imgproc.GC_PR_FGD)
                    {
                        buffer[y * width + x] = (byte)170; // probably foreground
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        buffer[y * width + x] = (byte)255; // for sure foreground
                    }
                }
            }
            mask.put(0, 0, buffer);
        }
```

For Each depth frame from Camera:

```
  Mat erodeElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(4, 4));
            Mat dilateElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(7, 7));
         

            depth.copyTo(maskFar);


            Core.normalize(maskFar, maskFar, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX, CvType.CV_8U);

            Imgproc.cvtColor(maskFar, maskFar, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
         
            Imgproc.threshold(maskFar, maskFar, 180, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
            Imgproc.dilate(maskFar, maskFar, erodeElement);
            Imgproc.erode(maskFar, maskFar, dilateElement);
          
            Mat bgModel = new Mat();
            Mat fgModel = new Mat();

            Imgproc.grabCut(image, maskFar, new OpenCVForUnity.CoreModule.Rect(), bgModel, fgModel, 1, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK);

            convertToGrayScaleValues(maskFar); // back to grayscale values
            Imgproc.threshold(maskFar, maskFar, 180, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);

            Mat foreground = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4, new Scalar(0, 0, 0));
            image.copyTo(foreground, maskFar);
          
            Utils.fastMatToTexture2D(foreground, texture);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provides detail for minimum reproducible works. By adding input RGB and depth image, then add the image that you wish the outcome to be.

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai I have provided Input RGB and depth image, and I want to cut out everything outside the monitor to be virtual reality world, so I want to cut out far objects and only show near objects like the monitor

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the graph cut on the depth image might not be the correct method to solve all of your issue.

If you insist the processing should be done in the depth image. To find everything that is not on the table and filter out the table part. You may first apply the disparity based approach  for finding the object that's is not on the ground. Reference: https://github.com/windowsub0406/StereoVision

[image]

Then based on the V disparity output image, find the locally connected component that is grouped together.  You may follow this link [how to do this disparity map in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62462522/how-to-do-this-disparity-map-in-opencv)  which is asking the similar way to find the objects that's not on the ground

If you are ok with RGB based approaches, then use any deep learning-based method to recognize the monitor should be the correct approaches.  It can directly detect the mointer bounding box. By apply this bounding box to the depth image, you may have what you want. For deep learning based approaches, there are many available package such as Yolo series. You may find one that is suitable for you. reference: https://medium.com/@dvshah13/project-image-recognition-1d316d04cb4c

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and for your answer. But I don't want to do object recognition, I just want to cut out the far objects and keep the near infront of my the camera, that's all. Nothing to do with object recognition at all. So I want to generate a mask that has values far away to be culled

Comment: The V disparity on depth image should be the way to go

Comment: Can you explain more about the use of V Disparity for cutting out far places and keep the one that are near to my eyes (depth). The thing is I'm doing mixed reality, and I would like to keep what I see inside a car for example and cut away the far objects

Comment: also Doctor, can you help with that question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797565/temporal-filtering-on-depth-image?noredirect=1#comment114566133_64797565

Comment: Related to the question, that's similar article that does what I want but they use two masks ? 
https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/rs-grabcuts

Comment: For v dispaity you may try this code here  https://github.com/thinkbell/v_disparity  To understand what is it you may refer to to this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5354207

Comment: The intel real sense one is a simple thresholding method that works well if you have enough foreground and background separation. At the base layer, this method may not work.

Comment: this video shows a simple threshold based method. if you only need this. then it is a lot easier to implment

Comment: After getting the v disparity how would I cut the windows of the car ? 
https://youtu.be/qUcimP-DIZk as shown here that's my experiement but I need a better cut out

Comment: @AhmedSaleh same thing. lets see whats the raw depth is. It might be just zed did not give good depth measurement

Comment: Yea, but that's another issue, I just want to cut out everything that around and want to show the virtual reality in a clean cut.

Comment: you proposed v disparity, I want to know how would I use it after getting it.

Comment: in this case, v disparity is not the correct way as it is for on road navigation and percept the environment. The original question and the new update makes it a different question already.  The one you want is different use case.